# Stopping & Restarting Services Remotely Using Set-Service

Tags: powershell, service

I've got a list of 10-15 services that I routinely need to restart on 6 servers. I have a script that calls a list of services, then calls a list of the servers, and then stops all the services:

```
$Services = Get-Content -Path "C:\Powershell\Services.txt"
$Machines = Get-Content -Path "C:\Powershell\Machines.txt"
Get-Service -Name $Services -ComputerName $Machines | Set-Service -Status Stopped
```

I then have another separate script to start them up again:

```
$Services = Get-Content -Path "C:\Powershell\Services.txt"
$Machines = Get-Content -Path "C:\Powershell\Machines.txt"
Get-Service -Name $Services -ComputerName $Machines | Set-Service -Status Running
```

I've checked around and can't seem to find a way of putting this into a single script. As I understand, Set-Service only has the ability to Stop, Start & Pause services, not restart them at the same time.

Any ideas? I might be missing something completely obvious.

Comment: Is anything in particular preventing you from simply using [`Restart-Service`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849823.aspx)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers -- When I read this, I assumed the OP needed the service to be stopped for an extended period of time to perform some operation that needed the service stopped.

Comment: @rory.ap Even then you'd use `Stop-Service` and `Start-Service`. That `Set-Service` can be (ab)used for stopping and starting services is incidental, and there are pitfalls to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To restart services simply use [`Restart-Service`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849823.aspx):

```
$Services = Get-Content -Path "C:\Powershell\Services.txt"
$Machines = Get-Content -Path "C:\Powershell\Machines.txt"
Get-Service -Name $Services -ComputerName $Machines | Restart-Service
```

Since according to the comments PowerShell v6 has removed support for remote access from the `*-Service` cmdlets you need to resort to `Invoke-Command` for remote execution when running v6 or newer, like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $Machines -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Service -Name $using:Services -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Restart-Service
}
```

or like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $Machines -ScriptBlock {
    Restart-Service $using:Services -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Another option would be WMI:

```
$fltr = ($Services | ForEach-Object { 'Name="{0}"' -f $_ }) -join ' or '
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Computer $Machines -Filter $fltr | ForEach-Object {
    $_.StopService()
    $_.StartService()
}
```

Comment: Note that -ComputerName has been removed in PowerShell v6, Luke's answer shows how it should work with v6.

Answer (score 2):

I am with Ansgar, this should work

```
$Services = Get-Content -Path "C:\Powershell\Services.txt"
$Machines = Get-Content -Path "C:\Powershell\Machines.txt"
foreach ($service in $services){
    foreach ($computer in $Machines){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock{
    Restart-Service -DisplayName $service}
    }
}
```

it is a little messy but should give you a starting point

Sorry I forgot to take time to explain what is going on, so you import each of your txt docs and then it will process for each service and each computer and restart the services.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this single liner command:

```
Get-Content .\services.txt | %{Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName (Get-Content .\computers.txt) -Filter "Name='$_'"} | %{$_.StopService()}; Get-Content .\services.txt | %{Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName (Get-Content .\computers.txt) -Filter "Name='$_'"} | %{$_.StartService()}
```